# Многопоточность и коллекция, c#

Tags: c#

Такая задача: получаю коллекцию, нужно каждую строку обработать обработать в новом потоке и опять все по новой. 
Проблема в том. что удалить строку с коллекции я могу лишь после ее обработки.

Реализовал пока так:

```
List<string> cash = new List<string>();

while(true){
    var rootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(result);
    foreach (var m in rootObject)
    {
        if (!cash.Contains(m.username))
        {
            cash.Add(m.username); //заношу в фильтр, что бы не было повторов
            Thr(m.username,m.amount);
        }
    }
}
...
void Thr(string username, decimal amount)
{
    new Thread(delegate ()
    {
     ....
     lock (locker)
     {
        cash.Remove(username); // удаляю из фильтра
     }
     //тут строка с отправкой запроса на удаление данной строки (я получаю лишь готовую коллекцию)
    }).Start();
}
```

Это плохой пример, как по мне, ибо иногда бывают пропуски (вдруг сервер долго обработает удаление, а в моем фильтре я уже удалил и будет повтор и т.п. и т.д.), можете предложить более хороший вариант ?

Comment: А зачем так сложно удалять то? Запуская поток! Это очень не быстрая и ресурсоемкая операция. И так же черевато повреждением данных при такой работе из разных тредов.

Comment: А цикл `while` точно должен быть бесконечным?

Comment: По сути, надо использовать LINQ с опцией AsParalel, если это необходимо, в чем есть явные сомнения.

Comment: @NewView коллекцию я получаю с сайта, и там довольно много данных, приходится подключать многопоточность, что бы все быстрее обрабатывалось

Comment: @SeeSharp это лишь пример, в проекте я юзаю флаг

Comment: Это заблуждение, с таким подходом будет только дольше, одназначно. Посмотрите в сторону LINQ

Comment: @Lolidze а ну тогда окей.

Comment: @NewView у меня обрабатывает одну строку примерно 5 минут, как правило, приходят пару десятков строк в коллекции, что будет очень долго обрабатывать, если поочередно делать, решил добавить многопоточность, мб сделать поток из пула, а не создание, но все равно это не решает основную проблему

Comment: @NewView я работал с linq, не прошу у вас готовый код, мне лишь нужная идея, как сделать одновременно и фильтр и многопоточность. Коллекцию я получаю, не могу просто так взять и удалить данные от туда, получаю я ее постоянно

Comment: Посмотрите тут [AsParalel](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/17.1.php) не стоит изобретать велосипед :)  Так напишите этот фильтр, там сравнения то элементарные, а к соурцу в linq добавьте метод AsParalel..

Comment: Его (linq вставку) можно крутить в цикле, а вот цикл можно запускать в отдельном треде. Это будет разумно.

Comment: @NewView да, спасибо, мне почему-то в голову даже не пришло о AsParallel, хотя раньше довольно часто применял, спасибо

Comment: Незачто :) и 5 символов..